# Exclude resource names using MS Project in VBA

Tags: vba, ms-project

I have a simple macro which updates a custom field in MS Project.  The problem is it counts the resource regardless, even when I try to exclude it.  For example, if a field contains "john" and "mark" it counts both of those resources when I just want it to count "mark".  When I debug it with a msgbox the code selects the correct data.

```
ignore case globally
Option Compare Text


Sub resourceCount2()
Dim ts As Tasks

    Set ts = ActiveProject.Tasks
    Dim t As Task

    For Each t In ts
        If Not t Is Nothing Then
            If Not t.Summary Then
                If Not t.ResourceNames Like "*JOHN*" Then
                t.Text2 = CStr(t.Resources.Count())
                End If
            End If
       End If
    Next t

End Sub
```

Comment: What do you mean by this?  Are "John" and "Mark" two different resources?  What are you putting into the MsgBox?  What do you expect to be different, and what value are you expecting?

Comment: Your code as written will look at the ResourceNames (which from documentation appears to just be a list of the names of all the resources), then if your resource name is not in there, It will return a count of all resources.  So if your resources were "John" and "Mark", then t.ResourceNames = "John,Mark" and your if statement as written will determine that "JOHN" is in the resource names and not put in the count.  If you instead searched for "*TIM*", it would put "2" in t.Text2 (the count of resources....)

Comment: Ok - so this iterates through each task, counts the number of resources per task and populates t.text2 with the count of the resources for that task.  The issue comes when I want to exclude a name from the count.  I want to exclude "john" from the count and only count the other resources for each task.  Looking at this again I can see my code is skipping the entire task when it sees "John" as one of the resources and only counting resources for tasks where "John" is not present.  Pls ignore my "this is correct in msgbox debug".

Comment: Fixed it - the following code counts every task resource containing "John" and subtracts that number from the total resources for that task.  Thanks for your help:

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it - the code now counts every task resource containing "John" and subtracts that number from the total resources for that task.

'ignore case globally
Option Compare Text

Sub resourceCount()
Dim ts As Tasks
Dim resources() As String

```
Set ts = ActiveProject.Tasks
Dim t As Task


    For Each t In ts

        Dim intCount As Integer
        Dim res_count As Integer
        res_count = 0

        resources = Split(t.ResourceNames, ",")

        For intCount = LBound(resources) To UBound(resources)
            total_resources = UBound(resources) + 1
            res_count = res_count + 1

                If Trim(resources(intCount)) Like "*John*" Then
                res_count = res_count - 1

                End If


        Next

        t.Text2 = res_count


Next t
```

End Sub